# Compact operators

Tags: compact-operators

From a textbook:

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $T : X \to Y$ is linear. Then $T$ is a **compact operator** if one of the following holds:
>
> (a) $\{Tx_n\}$ contains a convergent subsequence in $Y$ whenever $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequene in $X$.
>
> (b) The image of any bounded set $E$ in $X$ under $T$ has compact closure.

How can I show that (a) implies (b)?

Comment: I suppose $T$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a continous linear operator and $E$ be a bounded set in $X$

Let's call $F = T(E)$,

Now the non obvious part is to show that $\overline{F} \subset T(\overline{E})$, this follow from the closed graph theorem

Let's assume this property, and take $(y_n)$ a sequence in $\overline{F}$

Now, for each $y_n$, let's take an $x_n \in \overline{E}$ such that $Tx_n = y_n$. $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence, so $Tx_n = y_n$ has a converging subsequence, so $\overline{Y}$ is sequentially compact, hence compact.